# Archiving when uploading to artifactory

Tags: teamcity, artifactory

I'd like to use JFrog CLI and upload specs on my build server for uploading build artifacts to artifactory and later on, when moving e.g. to Teamcity, use the artifactory plugin to do the same thing. Our build artifacts are comprised of thousands of files and uploading them separately is slow compared to first archiving them and upload a few archives. The TeamCity built in artifact handling allows this though its "Artifact paths".

There is however no way, as far as I can see, to get the JFrog CLI or TeamCity Artifactory plugin to do the archiving for me except in the latter case using the now deprecated Legacy patterns.

That is unfortunate as I think it makes a lot of sense to be able to express what files should be archived in the upload step (i.e. the upload spec) instead of having a separate step for archiving and another for uploading. It seems even worse in TeamCity as the upload spec is applied to build steps (instead of a build configuration) so it would make even more sense to be able to express both archiving and uploading at the same time and place.

My questions are:

1) Am I correct in that there is no way go have the JFrog CLI do the archiving for me as part of uploading?

2) Why isn't archiving supported as part of upload in JFrog CLI and TeamCity plugin?

3) Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

1 & 2) You're right that the JFrog CLI doesn't have the ability to create archives of the files you're trying to upload. Generally speaking, the JFrog CLI is used to upload the output of a build and if that output contains multiple files you should probably keep those as separate files in JFrog Artifactory too. Having said that, the [JFrog CLI](https://github.com/jfrog/jfrog-cli-go/) is an open source project and we welcome ideas from the community to make the CLI better. If you could create a [new issue](https://github.com/jfrog/jfrog-cli-go/issues/new) in the GitHub repository with the details here and what your ideal workflow would be, the teams can investigate potential options.

3) To be honest, for the projects I have that end up with multiple files (like multiple executables), I want them uploaded separately. There is one project I have where I want to create a single archive with a bunch of files, so for that, I have a build step that creates a zipfile first (granted, this is in Jenkins and not TeamCity).

*disclaimer, I work for JFrog as a Developer Advocate*